# Possible bug in gcc when using member initializer

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, zeromq

**EDIT.** Finally, I have created the minimal working example regarding the original problem below (the interested reader can read up on the longish post that follows).

Basically, the following code excerpt is interpreted differently by `g++` and `clang++`, which was causing the headache:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct part {
  part() = default;
  template <class T> part(const T &) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
  }
};

struct message {
  message() = default;
  message(std::vector<part> parts) : parts_{std::move(parts)} {}

  std::size_t size() const noexcept { return parts_.size(); }

private:
  std::vector<part> parts_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  part p1{5}, p2{6.8};

  message msg = {{p1, p2}};

  std::cout << "msg.size(): " << msg.size() << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

When I compile the above code with `clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -O3 mwe.cpp -o mwe.out && ./mwe.out`, I get the following:

```sh
part::part(const T &) [T = int]
part::part(const T &) [T = double]
msg.size(): 2
```

When the same code is compiled with `g++`, instead, I get the following:

```sh
part::part(const T&) [with T = int]
part::part(const T&) [with T = double]
part::part(const T&) [with T = std::vector<part>]
msg.size(): 1
```

I would not expect to see the last `part::part(const T&) [with T = std::vector<part>]` call, though.

---

I am working on a project where I use 0MQ, and hence the `zeromq` tag.

I am experiencing a weird problem in my code which I am not sure is a bug in `g++` or in my wrapping the 0MQ library. I hope that I can get some help from you. Basically, I am testing against

```sh
~> g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 7.3.1 20180312
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

~> clang++ --version
clang version 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

You can find the [`zmq.hpp`](https://gist.github.com/aytekinar/3d434e8f5fe9f166512ca2df4c6d0ba9) file in my GitHub account, which I did not want to paste here because of its length. My minimal working example based on that header would then read:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "zmq.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  auto version = zmq::version();
  std::cout << "0MQ version: v" << std::get<0>(version) << '.'
            << std::get<1>(version) << '.' << std::get<2>(version) << '\n';

  zmq::message msg1, msg2;
  std::string p1{"part 1"};
  uint16_t p2{5};
  msg1.addpart(std::begin(p1), std::end(p1));
  msg1.addpart(p2);

  std::cout << "msg1 is a " << msg1.numparts() << "-part message.\n";
  std::cout << "msg1[0]: " << static_cast<char *>(msg1.data(0)) << '\n';
  std::cout << "msg1[1]: " << *static_cast<uint16_t *>(msg1.data(1)) << '\n';

  msg2 = {{msg1[0], msg1[1]}};

  std::cout << "msg2 is a " << msg2.numparts() << "-part message.\n";
  std::cout << "msg2[0]: " << static_cast<char *>(msg2.data(0)) << '\n';
  std::cout << "msg2[1]: " << *static_cast<uint16_t *>(msg2.data(1)) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code with

```sh
~> clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -O3 mwe.cpp -o mwe.out -lzmq
~> ./mwe.out
```

I see the following output:

```sh
0MQ version: v4.2.5
msg1 is a 2-part message.
msg1[0]: part 1
msg1[1]: 5
msg2 is a 2-part message.
msg2[0]: part 1
msg2[1]: 5
```

However, when I compile the code with

```sh
~> g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -O3 mwe.cpp -o mwe.out -lzmq
~> ./mwe.out
```

I get the following:

```sh
0MQ version: v4.2.5
msg1 is a 2-part message.
msg1[0]: part 1
msg1[1]: 5
msg2 is a 1-part message.
msg2[0]: <some garbage here>
fish: “./mwe.out” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Obviously, I am getting `SIGSEGV` due to my reading a memory location that I do not own. The interesting part is that when I change [Line 764](https://gist.github.com/aytekinar/3d434e8f5fe9f166512ca2df4c6d0ba9#file-zmq-hpp-L764) of the `zmq.hpp` file to read:

```cpp
// message::message(std::vector<part> parts) noexcept : parts_{std::move(parts)} {}
message::message(std::vector<part> parts) noexcept {
  parts_ = std::move(parts);
}
```

the code works as intended when compiled with both of the compilers.

In short, I would like to know if I am doing something fishy that results in the `g++`-compiled code's not working, or there is a possibility that `g++` has some bug. `g++` does not have the same behavior with simple dummy `struct`s that I use (that's why I could not write an MWE with simpler structs, and that's why I do suspect my wrappers). And, the same behavior is also observed with `-O0 -g` switches.

Thank you in advance for your time.

**EDIT.** I have changed the MWE to read as below (as per @Peter's comment):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "zmq.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  auto version = zmq::version();
  std::cout << "0MQ version: v" << std::get<0>(version) << '.'
            << std::get<1>(version) << '.' << std::get<2>(version) << '\n';

  zmq::message msg1, msg2;
  std::string data1{"part 1"};
  uint16_t data2{5};
  msg1.addpart(std::begin(data1), std::end(data1));
  msg1.addpart(data2);

  std::cout << "msg1 is a " << msg1.numparts() << "-part message.\n";
  // std::cout << "msg1[0]: " << static_cast<char *>(msg1.data(0)) << '\n';
  // std::cout << "msg1[1]: " << *static_cast<uint16_t *>(msg1.data(1)) << '\n';

  msg2 = {{msg1[0], msg1[1]}};

  std::cout << "msg2 is a " << msg2.numparts() << "-part message.\n";
  // std::cout << "msg2[0]: " << static_cast<char *>(msg2.data(0)) << '\n';
  // std::cout << "msg2[1]: " << *static_cast<uint16_t *>(msg2.data(1)) << '\n';

  zmq::message::part p1 = 5.0; // double
  std::cout << "[Before]: p1 has size " << p1.size() << '\n';
  zmq::message::part p2{std::move(p1)};
  std::cout << "[After]: p1 has size " << p1.size() << '\n';
  std::cout << "[After]: p2 has size " << p2.size() << '\n';

  zmq::message::part p3;
  std::cout << "[Before]: p3 has size " << p3.size() << '\n';
  p3 = std::move(p2);
  std::cout << "[After]: p2 has size " << p2.size() << '\n';
  std::cout << "[After]: p3 has size " << p3.size() << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

With `g++` and the original `zmq.hpp` file that I provide in the GitHub gist (well, this time `message::part` being `public`), I have the following:

```sh
0MQ version: v4.2.5
msg1 is a 2-part message.
msg2 is a 1-part message.
[Before]: p1 has size 8
[After]: p1 has size 0
[After]: p2 has size 8
[Before]: p3 has size 0
[After]: p2 has size 0
[After]: p3 has size 8
```

However, when I use `clang++`, I get the following:

```sh
0MQ version: v4.2.5
msg1 is a 2-part message.
msg2 is a 2-part message.
[Before]: p1 has size 8
[After]: p1 has size 0
[After]: p2 has size 8
[Before]: p3 has size 0
[After]: p2 has size 0
[After]: p3 has size 8
```

Both move construction and move assignment seem to work for `message::part` objects. Finally, `valgrind ./mwe.out` gives no leaks or errors.

**EDIT.** I have debugged the code over the weekend. It appears that `g++` is calling

```cpp
template <class T> message::part::part(const T &value) : part(sizeof(T)) {
  std::memcpy(zmq_msg_data(&msg_), &value, sizeof(T));
}
```

after `std::move` in

```cpp
message::message(std::vector<part> parts) noexcept : parts_{std::move(parts)} {}
```

For this reason, it creates a `vector` having only 1 `message::part`, which is (incorrectly) constructed with `value = {msg1[0], msg1[1]}`. However, `clang++` does the correct thing and does not call the templated constructor.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

**EDIT.** I have modified the code accordingly:

```cpp
struct message {
private:
  struct part {
    /* ... */
    part(const T &,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type * =
             nullptr);
    /* ... */
  };
    /* ... */
};

template <class T>
message::part::part(
    const T &value,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type *)
    : part(sizeof(T)) {
  std::memcpy(zmq_msg_data(&msg_), &value, sizeof(T));
}
```

Now, both `g++` and `clang++`-compiled binaries work without any problems. Apparently, SFINAE on the templated constructor disables the constructor call on `initializer_list`, which was getting called before, and the problem is resolved.

However, I still would like to know why `g++` prefers the templated constructor call to the normal move operation that was selected by `clang++`.

Comment: I haven't looked at your header but, from your description, a candidate for the cause is the move constructor of `part`.   If the change you describe alleviates the symptom, look for the difference between (1) default construct then move assignment (which works) and (2) move construction.   I wouldn't bet on it being a compiler bug - one "joy" of undefined behaviour is that it can seem to run correctly with one compiler but fail with another.

Comment: You appear to be adding an `std::string` to the `zmq::message` but then casting the return from `zmq::message::data` from `void *` to `char *`.  Your header code also appears to use `std::memcpy` to copy non-trivial types.

Comment: @G.M., thank you for the heads-up. What do you think I should use instead of `std::memcpy`? Should I resort to `std::copy` everywhere, or should I use `std::enable_if`, for instance, to enable copying of trivial types only? I doubt, though, this is the problem here, as I am not calling that constructor. I have used `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` to check the iterator, and I get `zmq::message::part::part(Iter, Iter) [with Iter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]` when constructing from `std::string`'s `begin` and `end` iterators.

Comment: @Peter, thank you for your answer. Should I check for the differences between the two in `part` or `message`?

Comment: @Arda - I suggest looking in the constructors and operators of `part`, since they are used in the constructor your changed.   Won't hurt to look at those functions in `message`, but (from your description) the constructor of `message` you changed doesn't use the move constructor or other operations of `message`.

Comment: @Peter, I think I have done what you asked for. Apparently, both move construction and move assignment operations are working as expected. However, when I construct a message from `parts`, I seem to lose them.

Comment: @Peter, I debugged the code at the weekend and I have updated my question. Any idea now?

Comment: You can simplify even further. Remove `message` completely and put this into `main`: `std::vector<part> vp1; std::vector<part> vp2{std::move(vp1)};`. And you can get rid of the member in `part`, which gets rid of the warnings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clang implemented [DR 1467](https://wg21.link/CWG1467) (brace-initializing a `T` from a `T` behaves as if you didn't use braces) but has yet to implement [DR 2137](https://wg21.link/CWG2137) (on second thought, do that only for aggregates).

Your `part` is implicitly convertible from everything under the sun, including `std::vector<part>`. Since `std::vector<part>` isn't an aggregate, post-DR2137 the usual two-phase overload resolution takes place for `parts_{std::move(parts)}` and selects the `initializer_list<part>` constructor, converting `std::move(parts)` into a `part`.

Comment: I will read more on this. Thank you very much for your answer. Basically, did I have this problem due to brace elision in the nested initializer list? Could you please elaborate on a possible solution to my problem? For instance, SFINAE on the templated constructor that prevents construction from anything but arithmetic types seems to have worked. Shall I stick to that one?

Comment: The rule for unicorn initialization is basically "if the arguments can somehow be contorted into matching an initializer-list constructor, use that constructor". One fix is to use parens instead of braces: `parts_(std::move(parts))`. And then there's `part` being implicitly convertible from anything and everything, which seems rather questionable, though I don't know enough about the library to be sure. Depending on the intended usage, SFINAE-constraining the constructor and/or making it explicit are all possible options.

Comment: I did not want to go for explicit construction in my use case; but definitely constraining it to my intended types would be best. I will replace the braces as per suggestion, tooo. Thank you very much for your help! I have already selected this as the answer. However, I need 18 more hours, apparently, to award the bounty points. Cheers!